# record max and min for the day

Tags: python, excel, vba, logic

I am trying to record a maximum and minimum price for the stock in excel. But when I try to do it change the values. I want to record the maximum and minimum value for the whole day the values are keep changing 0.25 per second I want the minimum  value for the whole day and maximum value for the whole day. there is only one reference which will change 0.25 per second
example:
in 1 min I have 240 values in a single cell I want the minimum and maximum value within the 1 min its tough to explain but I want it on excel. Please let me know the answers that will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Max() and min() will work, but if you change the data then the results can change…